# Escape characters in Jinja2 Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I am trying to create a Jinja2 Template to be used in an Ansible role and I really don't know how to escape double quotes in this template.

My code is like this:

```
{% for site in sites %}
testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="{{ site.path }}" enabled="true">
```

My variable is **site.path** and when I am adding double quotes ("") is not taken as a variable anymore.

How can I escape does character?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming sites is a list of dictionaries which includes a key called "path"

The following works for me where sites is a list of dictionaries:

```
{% for site in sites.values() %}
testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="{{ site.path }}" enabled="true">
{% endfor %}
```

The rendered template contains a "testclass" line for each dictionary in the list and site.path is interpolated

Comment: Site.path is indeed a variable from a list of dictionaries, but this works well and is correct. The problem is that I need the result of the value to have double quotes .
In the example you posted, same as mine, site.path will not be seen as a variable anymore because of the quotes.


I also tried with 2 double quotes, with /, but without success. I cannot escape them

 testname=""{{ site.path }}""
 testname=\"{{ site.path }}\"

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the output you need rendered? I am getting double quotes AND the variable value in my output from my test code. Thanks